# Convert an array of symbols into a list of items in ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Best way of converting the following data which is passed into a rails mailer

```
array = [:Jon, :Ben, :Penelope]
```

Into the body of the Rails Mailer as a list, so:

```
%{
Hi guys,

The following people are great:

Jon,
Ben,
Penelope

Thanks,
GreatCompany
}
```

Comment: For multiline strings you're better of using [*heredoc*](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents) than using the [`%{...}`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings) syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the best way, but I know you can use `join` passing the format you need ",\n":

```
array = [:Jon, :Ben, :Penelope]

puts %{
Hi guys,

The following people are great:

#{array.join(",\n")}

Thanks,
GreatCompany
}


# Hi guys,

# The following people are great:

# Jon,
# Ben,
# Penelope

# Thanks,
# GreatCompany
```